# Compiling C++ programs in Sublime Text 2

Tags: g++, sublimetext2

I installed the `git-cmd.bat` command prompt so I could do RoR. I forgot where I got this. Anyway, the `git-cmd.bat` has g++ installed or something (I don't know why and would love to learn!).

For class I need to make sure my projects run on visual studios and on g++. I like to write my programs in a sublime then transfer over to the ide to test then transfer back and fix code. This is getting very tedious and writing `g++ -o asdf *.cpp` every single time is not ideal.

When I do `ctrl+b` in sublime, it give me this error:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'C:\\Users\Desktop\\Project 2\\main.cpp', u'-o', u'C:\\Users\\\Desktop\\Project 2/main']]
[dir:  C:\Users\s\Desktop\Project 2]
[path: C:\windos\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin]
[Finished]
```

I thought g++ was already installed and since I can run g++ in my git command prompt, it should already be in path. Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks!

Comment: It didn't say it couldn't find g++, it says it could find 'the file'. Are you sure those paths are correct? Also, why are there 3 backslashes in last path in the array?

Comment: I deleted the folder with my name on it and was too lazy to delete the slashes with it. I'll check the path again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hey not sure if you figured this out, but it is checking the directories listed in path.

So you'll have to add the path to g++ in the system path: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

or where it says "g++" you'll have to add the absolute path to the executable. For example, instead of downloading MinGW twice, I have linked to the Code::Blocks (my IDE of choice) version of MinGW and the "g++" now says:

C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\g++

(each slash is twice above, StackOverflow is escaping the string)

I'm not familiar with the "git-cmd.bat prompt" you mention, but if it does have g++ you'd have to find the path to it and do one of the above. If StackOverflow/Google can't shed light on this I would recommend just doing a search for g++ in Windows Explorer.